# In JS ES6, why is it that if I export default, then I cannot export it individually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I found that I can do:

```
export function Foo() {
  return <div>hello</div>;
}

export default Foo;
```

but I cannot move that `default` to the top:

```
export default function Foo() {
  return <div>hello</div>;
}

export Foo;
```

Why is that?  They just seem to serve the same purpose: export `Foo` as default and individually, but the first form is ok while the second form is not.

Comment: `export Foo;` is not valid syntax. Are you using typescript perchance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't quite tell if this is a language quirk, because I never see a bare `export SymbolName`, but changing the last line to this *is* valid:

```
export { Foo };
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
export { Foo as Foo };
```

I suspect it simply has to do with the fact that the syntax generally is:

```
export [function|const|class|let] Foo ...etc...
```

MDN has a [great list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) of all the different ways you can export.

I don't have an answer as to *why* `export Foo` doesn't work

Comment: Isn't `export { Foo }` actually equivalent to `export { Foo: Foo } literally?

Comment: @RandyCasburn in `import` and `export`, it's not `{Foo: Foo}` but `{Foo as Foo}`

Comment: @RandyCasburn If it was `export default { Foo }` it would be; just `export { Foo }` would be the named export, but it's not an object literal in that context, e.g., you can't write `export { Foo: Bar }`.

Comment: Right, So I misconstrued the spec. Behind the scenes the export name is bound to the module identifier with the same name. Just like any other environment record binding. But, obviously, that doesn't translate to the language syntax directly. I've never tried to write it as an object literal (who would?), but after a little trial it's easy to see. Thanks for the clarity.

Comment: "*I don't have an answer as to why `export Foo` doesn't work*" - it's obviously not permitted by the spec, isn't that just enough? :-) Not sure what you'd even expect it to do.

Comment: @Bergi, well that answers the question of why it fails, but not why it's written like that in the spec. I would expect `export Foo` to behave as `export { Foo }`.

Comment: But 'because the spec said so' I guess is _one_ way to answer it =)

Comment: @Evert It's written with braces because it's a list and those need delimiters. I mean, we could do without them grammatically, but they're useful visually and reflect the usage of braces in import statements, whose syntax was discussed [here](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/moduleimport#content-76) at length (not certain that's the actual rationale, but it's the only argument I could find in the archives).

Comment: Nice, that definitely sounds more like a good reason. Ty!